# Getting reCaptcha Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, recaptcha

I trying to get reCaptcha-code for send to Firebase server. Read [here](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/recaptcha#kotlin), implement Executor to Activity and write this code at onClick:

```
override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        SafetyNet.getClient(this).verifyWithRecaptcha("Here i write my API Key")
            .addOnSuccessListener(this as Executor, OnSuccessListener { response ->
                val userResponseToken = response.tokenResult
                Log.d("TAG", userResponseToken.toString())
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(this as Executor, OnFailureListener { e ->
                if (e is ApiException) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Error: ${CommonStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(e.statusCode)}")
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Error: ${e.message}")
            })
```

Logs are not printing when I click button and call onClick method, but this method works. Tell me please, what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this and it works without using the `as Executor` like the below example:

```
SafetyNet.getClient(this)
    .verifyWithRecaptcha("MY API KEY")
    .addOnSuccessListener(this, OnSuccessListener { response ->
        // Indicates communication with reCAPTCHA service was successful.
        val userResponseToken = response.tokenResult
        if (response.tokenResult?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
            // Validate the user response token using the
            // reCAPTCHA siteverify API.
        }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(this, OnFailureListener { e ->
        if (e is ApiException) {
            // An error occurred when communicating with the
            // reCAPTCHA service. Refer to the status code to
            // handle the error appropriately.
            Log.d("TAG", "Error: ${CommonStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(e.statusCode)}")
        } else {
            // A different, unknown type of error occurred.
            Log.d("TAG", "Error: ${e.message}")
        }
    })
```

Comment: I delete it, it doesnt work now to

Comment: @Keworker did you remove also the implementation of Executor in your Activity? What error are you getting now?

Comment: Now, when i press button showing dialog window of recaptcha, but logs of listeners dont work. Yes, i remove implementation of executor

Comment: @Keworker what version of safetynet are you using? I have tested the above code with the latest version: com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:18.0.1  and it works perfect i am getting a userResponseToken correctly. Try to put a breakpoint in each block inside the addOnSuccessListener and inside the addOnFailureListener and check which place it is been called.